# Law of total probability given it belongs to A

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given that $P_y(y) =\sum P_{y|x}(y|x)·P_x(x)$ Law of total probability.
Prove that for any given event A
 $P_y(y∈A) =∑P_{y|x}(y∈A|x)·P_x(x)$

I tried to define y∈A and tried solving it using the compliment of the event. I am not able to arrive at the intended outcome

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions. Also, in order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: Sure. will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to define $y\in A$ and tried solving it using the compliment of the event.

You do not need the compliment.   You need the additivity of disjoint unions.   For any discrete random variable, $Y$, and set of measures, $A~$:

$$\mathsf P_{\small Y}(A)~=~\sum_{y\in A}\mathsf P_{\small Y}(y)$$

Comment: So after this step I just have to change the limits of summation and arrive at the outcome?

Comment: After this step, substitute $\mathsf P_{\small Y}(y)=\sum_{x\in X(Y^{-1}(y))}\mathsf P_{\small Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\mathsf P_{\small X}(x)$ and *then* consolidate the summations.